# Performance - Array.forEach vs implemented version

Tags: javascript, foreach

I would have expected a native version to be faster.

What gives?

http://jsperf.com/native-vs-implmented-0

**Implementation**

```
function each (obj, func, context) {
    var kindex,
        length;
    for (kindex = 0, length = obj.length; kindex < length; kindex++) {
        func.call(context, obj[kindex], kindex, obj);
    }
}
```

**Test Cases**

```
// implemented
each([0,1,2,3], function(val){
    val++;
})
```

vs

```
// native
[0,1,2,3].forEach(function(val){
    val++
})
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, this is how Array.forEach is implemented internally. As you see there are many checks involved and not straight forward as your implementation.

Refer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

```
if ( !Array.prototype.forEach ) {
 
  Array.prototype.forEach = function forEach( callback, thisArg ) {
 
    var T, k;
 
    if ( this == null ) {
      throw new TypeError( "this is null or not defined" );
    }
 
    // 1. Let O be the result of calling ToObject passing the |this| value as the argument.
    var O = Object(this);
 
    // 2. Let lenValue be the result of calling the Get internal method of O with the argument "length".
    // 3. Let len be ToUint32(lenValue).
    var len = O.length >>> 0; // Hack to convert O.length to a UInt32
 
    // 4. If IsCallable(callback) is false, throw a TypeError exception.
    // See: http://es5.github.com/#x9.11
    if ( {}.toString.call(callback) !== "[object Function]" ) {
      throw new TypeError( callback + " is not a function" );
    }
 
    // 5. If thisArg was supplied, let T be thisArg; else let T be undefined.
    if ( thisArg ) {
      T = thisArg;
    }
 
    // 6. Let k be 0
    k = 0;
 
    // 7. Repeat, while k < len
    while( k < len ) {
 
      var kValue;
 
      // a. Let Pk be ToString(k).
      //   This is implicit for LHS operands of the in operator
      // b. Let kPresent be the result of calling the HasProperty internal method of O with argument Pk.
      //   This step can be combined with c
      // c. If kPresent is true, then
      if ( Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(O, k) ) {
 
        // i. Let kValue be the result of calling the Get internal method of O with argument Pk.
        kValue = O[ k ];
 
        // ii. Call the Call internal method of callback with T as the this value and
        // argument list containing kValue, k, and O.
        callback.call( T, kValue, k, O );
      }
      // d. Increase k by 1.
      k++;
    }
    // 8. return undefined
  };
}
```

Comment: This is how it's shimmed to match as closely as possible the steps required in ECMAScript. I wouldn't go so far as to say that's how it's done internally.

Comment: "This algorithm is exactly the one specified in ECMA-262, 5th edition" from mozilla.

Comment: right ... it would likely be written in compiled language, when implemented in the browser ...

Answer (score 6):

`forEach()` does more than your implementation. If you don't need the extra effort that the official algorithm performs, a simple implementation like yours is indeed preferable when raw speed is required.

The 'official' algorithm is described in [the MDN reference for `Array.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

Comment: *"context binding"* Are you suggesting that the native `.forEach()` actually does something similar to the native `.bind()`? If so, it doesn't. It just sets the `this` value of the function it's invoking.

Comment: ...what does it do `more` than my `simple implementation`?

Comment: @pure_code.mom [here is a Gist](https://gist.github.com/robertklep/13b0ec93a677d58bbfdd) that shows different behaviour for `each` and `forEach` (at least in Node). Assuming that `forEach` is implemented per the ES description of the algorithm, `each` doesn't conform.