# How to simplify and speed up _.each?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

The native `Array.prototype.forEach()` is very slow.  I don't know why.  Also, I don't know why it is implemented in [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/#each)'s `_.each()`.  I think people generally think that if it is in a library, or it is implemented by a browser, that it is correct/efficient until proven not correct/efficient.

Here is the proof:

http://jsperf.com/native-vs-implmented-0

If we simply remove the native call from [underscore,  _.each](https://github.com/documentcloud/underscore/blob/master/underscore.js#L77), we get:

```
  var each = _.each = _.forEach = function(obj, iterator, context) {
    if (obj == null) return;
    if (obj.length === +obj.length) {
      for (var i = 0, l = obj.length; i < l; i++) {
        if (iterator.call(context, obj[i], i, obj) === breaker) return;
      }
    } else {
      for (var key in obj) {
        if (_.has(obj, key)) {
          if (iterator.call(context, obj[key], key, obj) === breaker) return;
        }
      }
    }
  };
```

I plan on asking the underscore team as well, but I wanted to verify I did not miss anything obvious.

Is this a valid reduction that will enhance performance?  Is the performance hit taken in the hope that one day it will be faster? Can this reduction be made to enhance performance without losing *useful* functionality?

Comment: take a look at this fiddle http://jsperf.com/native-vs-implmented-0/5 If you correctly implement all required type checks the result will be quite the opposite. Checking for actual presence of a property with `Object.prototype.hawOwnProperty`adds significant overhead.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko - that's a good point, but since the question had to do with the native `forEach()`, we can assume we're talking about iterating over an *`Array`* and not an `Object`. So Underscore uses a numeric `for` loop and not a `for..in` loop. Therefore the `hasOwnProperty` test isn't needed.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko: The implemented version should have an `in` test instead of a `hasOwnProperty` test. Not sure what performance difference that makes, but it's not quite a standard implementation when using `.hasOwnProperty`

Comment: @MichaelGeary: Still checking for ith property to be actually defined is required by spec. 
Consider the following code:
`function each (obj, func, context) {
        var kindex,
            length;
        for (kindex = 0, length = obj.length; kindex < length; kindex++) {
            func.call(context, obj[kindex], kindex, obj);
        }
    }
var arr = Array(100);
each(arr, function(item, idx){console.log(idx)});
arr.forEach(function(item, idx){console.log(idx)});`
Implemented each will print all indices while it shouldn't.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko: To be clear, by "implemented version" I meant an implementation of the spec, which would be the MDN version in your jsPerf. I looked too quickly at the names. MDN's version isn't quite compliant.

Comment: See [Performance - Array.forEach vs implemented version](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15930271/performance-array-foreach-vs-implemented-version) for the *Why?*

Comment: @YuryTarabanko - You're right about that. This is why it is so useful to write your own simple iterator instead of the standard one: because you don't have to comply with any specification. Customize it to your needs, just don't call it `Array.prototype.forEach()`. I'll bet that in the most common uses of these iterators, you simply don't have to worry about a missing element. Most of the time it's going to be an array you made yourself, or a JSON array. In the rare case where you have to handle missing elements, you can do it in the callback function or use a different iterator function.

Comment: @CrazyTrain: Have a look at this test: http://jsperf.com/hasownproperty-vs-in/2. Even `in` is slow compared to simply accessing the property.

Comment: @FelixKling: Interesting. Given that in the case of `.forEach()`, the properties will almost always be defined, I wonder if it would be a worthwhile optimization actually retrieve the value first, and then only do the `in` test if the value came back as `undefined`. Maybe I'll do a quick jsPerf.

Comment: @FelixKling: http://jsperf.com/native-vs-implmented-0/6 Seems to make more of a difference in Chrome than Firefox. I see that the MDN compatibility patch is now non-compliant in *two* ways. I've tracked their patches for a while, and whenever someone comes along and fixes them, it isn't long before some other guy who apparently thinks he knows what he's doing because he read a Crockford book, makes some incompatible change. I don't think I can recommend these MDN patches anymore.

Answer (score 7):

Take a look at [Lo-Dash](http://lodash.com/). The author has done a lot of work looking into these performance issues, especially in [this blog post](http://kitcambridge.be/blog/say-hello-to-lo-dash/) and [this video](http://vimeo.com/48576012).

If performance is your goal, you may be best served by writing your own iterator that does only what you need and nothing else—then it should perform very well. For example, in many cases you only need the array element and not the index. You definitely don't need to use `.call()` to pass the array element to the callback as `this`, since it's being passed as a named argument too. And do you really need to make `return false;` in the callback terminate the loop? I can't remember the last time I used that. So it could be as simple as:

```
function eachElement( array, callback ) {
    for( var i = 0, n = array.length;  i < n;  ++i ) {
        callback( array[i] );
    }
}
```

It's going to be hard to beat that for speed.

You can have a separate version when you need the index:

```
function eachElementAndIndex( array, callback ) {
    for( var i = 0, n = array.length;  i < n;  ++i ) {
        callback( array[i], i );
    }
}
```

You might use shorter function names; I just used these long names for clarity here. And it may turn out that `eachElementAndIndex()` is fast enough, so you might just call it `each()` and be done with it.

It's worth noting, as [@YuryTarabanko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/351705/yury-tarabanko) points out in a comment above, that these simplified iterators don't meet the specification for `Array.prototype.forEach()`. In addition to not passing the array element as `this` and not passing the entire array as a third parameter, they don't check for missing elements and will call the callback for every array index from `0` through `array.length - 1` regardless of whether the array elements actually exist. For example.

In fact, Underscore.js's `_.each()` is inconsistent in this regard. When it falls back to `Array.prototype.forEach()`, it skips missing elements, but when it uses its own `for` loop it includes them.

Try going to [underscorejs.org](http://underscorejs.org/) and paste this into the Chrome console:

```
function eachElementAndIndex( array, callback ) {
    for( var i = 0, n = array.length;  i < n;  ++i ) {
        callback( array[i], i );
    }
}

function log( e, i ) {
    console.log( i + ':', e );
}

var array = [];
array[2] = 'two';

console.log( 'eachElementAndIndex():' );
eachElementAndIndex( array, log );

console.log( '_.each() using native .forEach():' );
_.each( array, log );

console.log( '_.each() using its own loop:' );
var saveForEach = Array.prototype.forEach;
delete Array.prototype.forEach;
_.each( array, log );
Array.prototype.forEach = saveForEach;

console.log( 'Done' );
```

It logs:

```
eachElementAndIndex():
0: undefined
1: undefined
2: two
_.each() using native .forEach():
2: two
_.each() using its own loop:
0: undefined
1: undefined
2: two
Done
```

In many (probably most) cases, missing elements don't matter. Either you're working with an array you created, or a JSON array, and you know it doesn't have any missing elements. For JSON arrays in particular, this is never an issue, because JSON doesn't have a way to make an array with missing elements. A JSON array can have *`null`* elements, but `.forEach() includes those like any other.

As long as your simplified iterator does what you want and isn't named `Array.prototype.forEach`, you don't have to worry about it meeting any specification other than your own. But if you do need to skip over missing array elements, take that into account in your own code or use the standard `.forEach()`.

Also, just to simplify the Underscore code you're looking at a bit further, since we're talking about `.forEach()`, that means we're only talking about the `Array` portion of `_.each()`, not the `Object` portion. So the actual code path of interest is just this:

```
  var each = _.each = _.forEach = function(obj, iterator, context) {
    if (obj == null) return;
    if (obj.length === +obj.length) {
      for (var i = 0, l = obj.length; i < l; i++) {
        if (iterator.call(context, obj[i], i, obj) === breaker) return;
      }
    }
  };
```